# SSIS problems with MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3.8

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

I am having a problem with a SSIS project that downloads data from a MySQL database and insert it in a SQL Server 2014 Database.

So I have two versions of the same project, one for SQL Server 2016 and another one for SQL Server 2014. They have the same scripts and data flows, but for some reason, only the one made for SQL Server 2016 works. The issues resides in the ODBC Driver connector. I can preview data in both project, but for the SQL Server 2014 version, it simply won't load it. So I get 0 rows every time I run it. Sadly, I need the 2014 version for our SQL Server, since when I deploy the project with 2016 as target version, it fails.

This pretty much sum up the whole problem and I have try quite a few things. Including, changing the ODBC connector's version. It all seems it has something to do with Visual Studio, when the target version is change from 2016 to 2014. Still, I can't find a solution to this issue.

I am using a query to source data, but I also tried with the table name, but still didn't work. I am not using any function. I am running directly from Visual Studio in debug mode.

Has anyone gone through the same error? I can't find anything related.

Please, let me know if you need anything else to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had similar issue but it was in Source query where one of function was not behaving same between 2016 and 2014 version.

- When you say 0 rows, does package failed or successful ?
- Are you using a query to source data ? If yes, does it have any functions used ?
- Are you running from BIDS or SQL Agent ? If Sql Agent, Check if agent job configured to run in same 32bit or 63 bit version ?

Comment: The package runs and it doesn't fail, but still won't load any data. I get 0 rows, even though I can clearly see the data in preview.

Yes, I am using a query to source data, but I also tried with the table name, but still didn't work. I am not using any function.

I am running directly from Visual Studio in debug mode.